# Ember {{each}} vs {{each x in controller}}

Tags: ember.js

When i use {{each}} for example:

```
{{#each imagepost}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{else}}
    empty :O
{{/each}}
```

I get the 'empty :O' message

When i do it like this:

```
{{#each imagepost in controller}}
    <li>{{imagepost.title}}</li>
{{else}}
    empty :O
{{/each}}
```

It works fine!

It is weird cause the docs says to do it like this:

```
  {{#each people}}
    <li>Hello, {{name}}!</li>
  {{/each}}
```

Which doesnt work for me =/

Does the shortened version won't apply to models? only to controller's properties?

Comment: I think it depends on where you have that array of data. If your array is called under your router, you can use the shorthand like you are trying to, but if it is in the controller directly then you would have to state explicitly that it is located in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shortened version only applies to properties on the controller/model or the controller/model.  In your case it would be:

```
{{#each controller}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{else}}
    empty :O
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each model}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
{{else}}
    empty :O
{{/each}}
```

Note, if you do `{{#each model}}` and you have an `itemController` defined on the array controller it won't wrap each item with the item controller, you would need to do this: `{{#each model itemController='foo'}}`.

Comment: Thanks the shortened version isn't explained that well in the docs :)